# Hawt IO - Dozer tab is not appearing in hawtio

Tags: spring, apache-camel, dozer, hawtio

I am using hawtio web version using 1.4.17. My application is build on Apache camel using spring DSL. We are using Dozer mapping for pojo to pojo mapping. 
I have given hawtio-dozer & hawtio-dozer-schemagen as maven dependency. Still the dozer related items are not getting exposed as MBean. Hence they are not availble in hawt io console.
We have instatiated Dozer mapping via static helper classes. please let me know if I am missing something or doing it wrong way to it listed in hawtio console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dozer is available in the wiki tab, where you can create a new dozer mapping file, or open an existing file. Then there is an UI editor to edit and map between POJOs using dozer.

Mind the data mapper UI is not feature complete, and will be improved in the future. We are just busy with other things on our plate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dozer section is available in WIKI tab. Is there a way edit existing mappings available in JVM?

Comment: No, if you edit in JVM you cannot persist the changes. It really only make sense to do the UI mapping on the source code.